# Need help returning the biggest 3 consecutive number in a string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I am given a string of numbers as a parameter in my function. I need to find the biggest 3 digit consecutive number and return it.

```
function largestThreeDigitNum(numString){

    let largestNumber = 0;
    let largestThreeNumber = 0; 

    for(let i= 0; i<numString.length; ++i){
        if(numString[i] === largestNumber){
            largestThreeNumber = largestNumber++
        }
    }
    return largestThreeNumber; 
}
```

Comment: please add some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small script that returns the 3 largest consecutive numbers, hope it will help you

```js
function largestThreeDigitNum(numString) {
  var numbers = [];
  
  // Loop to fill an array with all 3 consecutive numbers
  for (var i = 0; i < numString.length - 2; i++) { 
    numbers.push(numString.slice(i, i + 3));
  }

  numbers.sort() // sort the array from the smallest to the biggest
  return numbers[numbers.length - 1] // return the last item of the array, the biggest one
}

console.log(largestThreeDigitNum("693759936") )
```

Answer (score 0):

OK let's assume that your input string is something like "123 465 789". You can split it over spaces, keep only 3 digit numbers, sort it, take the last three.

```js
largestThreeDigitNum = numString => numString
                                       .split(" ") // split it over spaces
                                       .filter(n => n.length === 3) // keep only 3 digit numbers
                                       .sort()
                                       .slice(-3) // take the last three

console.log( largestThreeDigitNum("56 456 321 78 987 123 741 2 96 41 58 654") )
```

Comment: Thank you@jeremyThile!  This is great! Only, how would it change if needed 3 consecutive numbers?

Comment: What do you mean consecutive? 123 -> 124 -> 125? Or consecutive in the input string? With or without other numbers in-between allowed? etc.

Comment: @BethHowell, please add some exampels and the wanted results.

Comment: @ninaScholz ...sorry, super new to coding and first question.  An example would be a string of numbers ie '12837469' . have to return the largest of 3 consecutive: 837

Answer (score 0):

Here's a verbose way that attempts to break the problem down into several small problems and solve those problems with small functions. Essentially we:

- Convert the string into an array
- Split the array into chunks of three, or as near to three as possible
- Filter out the chunks which aren't three numbers long
- Convert the chunks of 3 'number' strings to a single number
- Go through each number, keeping a record of the largest
- Return the largest

If you need something fast then this is not the most efficient solution and you'd be better off with something else. But if you're interested in having a solution which is built from small, composable chunks, then this might be good for you.

```js
const splitIntoAllChunks = size => array => Object.values(
  array
    .reduce((prev, _, i) => ({
      ...prev,
      [i]: array.slice(i, i + size),
    }), {})
);
  
const splitIntoThrees = splitIntoAllChunks(3);

const isLength = length => array => array.length === length;

const stringArrayToNumber = array => Number(array.join(''));

const getMax = (champ, challenger) => challenger > champ ? challenger : champ;

const example = "184727158129123"

const result = splitIntoThrees(example.split(''))
  .filter(isLength(3))
  .map(stringArrayToNumber)
  .reduce(getMax, 0);
  
console.dir(result);
```

If you want to go with something a bit more like your original solution, then you could fix it up a little with something like this:

```js
const testData = "1234596789"

function largestThreeDigitNum(numString){

    // this could be passed into the function instead, that way
    // the same code could be used for numbers of different sizes
    let numberSize = 3;

    // we only care about the largest three digit number at any given time
    let largestThreeNumber = 0; 

    // I've changed this to i++ as it's a little more conventional that way
    // I've also setup the loop to stop as soon as it can
    for (let i = 0; i < numString.length - (numberSize - 1); i++){
 
        // find the number for comparison
        const thisNumber = Number(numString.slice(i, i + 3))
        
        // if it's the biggest number, keep track of it
        if(thisNumber > largestThreeNumber){
            largestThreeNumber = thisNumber;
        }
    }
    return largestThreeNumber; 
}

console.dir(largestThreeDigitNum(testData))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a temporary array and check the values.

```js
var array = [101, 102, 103, 307, 308, 309, 211, 215, 227, 249, 479, 480, 481, 901, 902, 635, 636, 637],
    temp = [],
    largest = array.reduce((r, b, i, { [i - 1]: a }) => {
        if (a !== b - 1) {
            temp = [b];
            return r;
        }
        temp.push(b);
        if (temp.length > 3) temp.shift();
        if (temp.length === 3 && (!r || r[0] < temp[0])) return temp.slice();
        return r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(largest);
```